# Stop wrapping of hyphenated text?

Tags: html

I have a bunch of links in a div. Some have format "some-name". those with hyphen will split and wrap. I would like it to start a new line. How to do this please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the CSS attribute: `white-space:nowrap;` But note that it is not working all the time on some browser.

The other option is to wrap your link into a `<pre>` element but this approach can have some side effects as well.

Answer (score 23):

You can use a non-breaking hyphen character, `&#8209;`

Answer (score 6):

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap;">some-name</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

turn off formatting with

```
<pre>...</pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also do this:

```
<nobr>Table-text</nobr>
```

Reference:

[How to prevent line break at hyphens on all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753296/how-to-prevent-line-break-at-hyphens-on-all-browsers)

Comment: Probably because it's not good practice to recommend [Non-Standard and Obsolete html tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete).  Per the World Wide Web Consortium - `Elements in the following list are entirely obsolete, and must not be used by authors: ... nobr ...`