# In HTML text don't break at the existing hyphen in the text

Tags: html, css, browser

I have some text that contains hyphen (-). When the text is long enough to not fit in the container, it is wrapped.

When a hyphenated word is encountered towards the end of the line, all major browsers except Firefox break that hyphenated word on the hyphen.

I want to keep the Firefox behavior across my target browsers (Opera, Safari, Chrome, IE9+(good-to-have))

On Firefox, the behavior is seen even on resizing. Here is the markup:

```
<h2>Testing awesome hyphens  vvvcsvdcsacscsaccccc asvcvadcvdvv-ysys sdcvsdvavv</h2>

h2 { font-size: 2em; margin: 15px 0 10px; }
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EMJ73/1/). Open it in Firefox v/s other browsers to see different behaviors.(Resize the containers as required)

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: The question is about *allowing* line break, not preventing it.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela yes that's correct...I want to allow breaks as the text is almost certainly going to exceed its containers' width..I just dont want word to break line on hyphen

Comment: Actually I first misread the question (perhaps due to its title). This is about preventing line break after a hyphen, and it is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: My apologies...I agree it is a duplicate..guess I have to replace any hyphenated text in that container with a non-breaking hyphen (HTML: &#8209;) as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8753317/405117

Comment: I have voted to close