# Rurn off word break in case of font-face

Tags: css, font-face

When I'm using font-face I have a word-break problem, with tense which include dashes.

With the standard font, everything works well.
HTML (This is Georgian language)

```
<p>მობილური აპლიკაცია Sმარტივი-ს მომხმარებლებისათვის</p>
```

Here is computed css:

```
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-family: lb-default;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 18.5714092254639px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 184.5px;
```

P.S. Text is inside of bootstrap grid cell.

Comment: Do you want to text to stop getting hyphens on one line, or you want to remove hyphens completely? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

First set the `lang` attribute on the `html` tag, then use:

```
-moz-hyphens: none;
-ms-hyphens: none;
-webkit-hyphens: none;
 hyphens: none;
```

Comment: For some reason it looks like chrome stopped supporting this even with the prefix: http://caniuse.com/#search=hyp. Whats strange is CSS tricks shows the prefix once working: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/

Comment: @Lasharela Try setting the `lang` attribute on the `html` tag.

Comment: I've found "Georgian's" ISO for lang attribute (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp) but that doesn't work.

Also chrome doesn't recognize: `hyphens: none; -webkit-hyphens: none;`

Answer (score 0):

I've just found partial solution:

> You can use a Unicode NON-BREAKING HYPHEN (U+2011): ‑. HTML entity:

```
&#8209;
```

[How to prevent line break at hyphens on all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753296/how-to-prevent-line-break-at-hyphens-on-all-browsers)