# HTML - Text flow

Tags: html

We have a responsive website with a block containing the phrase '**for the chance of winning X - sign up to our e-newsletter**" in a p tag.

Annoyingly at a certain resolution we see '**e-**' on one line and '**newsletter**' on the next - my question is whether its possible for the hyphen to be classed as part of the word - so it would break onto the next line as a whole rather than in part (as a standard word would do)?

Any ideas?

Comment: What CSS do you have for that (or any) p tag? Wihout any additional styling it should do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I would do ;)

Wrap a [span](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/span-html-element/) tag around the word you would like to control uniquely:

`<span class="e">e-newsletter</span>`

*Now you have it as it's own element, with a selector to do what you'd like with!*

```
.e { 
   // display inline-block perhaps?
   // give it a set width maybe?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A way I would consider is the `<nobr></nobr>` tag:
[How to prevent line break at hyphens on all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753296/how-to-prevent-line-break-at-hyphens-on-all-browsers)

`<nobr>e-newsletter</nobr>`