# Keep words containing a dash (-) from breaking?

Tags: html, css

Is there a css property that will text like `--TestCanvas-min-width` from breaking on the `-`?  I've tried `word-break: keep-all`, but it still breaks on the dash.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753296/how-to-prevent-line-break-at-hyphens-on-all-browsers

Comment: Perhaps substitute the dash for a [non-breaking hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7691604/2418006)

Comment: Is it a dash or two hyphens? [google](https://www.google.ca/search?safe=off&ei=PEYkW678C9KS0PEP4oij0A0&q=dash+vs+hyphen&oq=dash+vs&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0l10.2354.3698.0.5060.7.7.0.0.0.0.72.464.7.7.0..2..0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.7.463...0i131k1j35i39k1j0i67k1j0i131i67k1.0.ZHnvGUDb5S8)

Comment: It breaks on the `-` ... you should be able to see it in this css test https://superflycss.github.io/component-test/target/test/html/  It's the third test ... resize the viewport to see the breaks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like `white-space: nowrap;`.

you can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

so you would add `<span>` and apply that to it.

```css
.my--div {
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.my--span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="my--div">--TestCanvas-min-width--TestCanvas-min-width--TestCanvas-min-width<span class="my--span">--TestCanvas-min-width--</span>TestCanvas-min-width</div>
```