# Break word at specific character

Tags: html, css, class, word-wrap

I realise that similar questions have been asked, but none quite like this.

I have a situation where I am using BEM to display some classes in `code` tags. Below is an example:

[image]

Obviously the default behaviour is to break words at a hyphen, as we can see is happening in the example. Is there a way that I can control what characters the line-break occurs at? I would like to be able to have class name integrity maintained so that the line break occurs before each period `.`  if necessary.

Comment: Depending on what flexibility you have with your html structure and / or modifying the strings, you may find something useful here: [How to prevent line breaks at hyphens...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753296/how-to-prevent-line-break-at-hyphens-on-all-browsers)

Comment: would you like to do with query?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to do everything you want with pure CSS.

UPDATE: removed spaces before periods in JS solution.

If you are able to use JavaScript you could process the `code` tag's contents to disable wrapping for words with hyphens and you could wrap each block starting with a period in an `inline-block` span.

The following code breaks the contents of each `code` tag into a list of blocks that start with either space or period. Each block is wrapped with a span that prevents wrapping, and blocks that begin with a period are additionally marked as `display: inline-block;`. This should give the behaviour you are looking for, and additionally preserve all content when copy-pasting text.

CSS:

```
.no-wrap-hyphen {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.wrap-period {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JavaScript (run this function on window load and resize):

```
function wrapPeriodsNotHyphens() { // run on window load or resize
    var codes = document.getElementsByTagName( "code" );

    for ( var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++ ) {

        currentCode = codes[ i ].innerHTML.split(/(?=[ .])/); // split by spaces and periods

        for ( var c = 0; c < currentCode.length; c++ ) {
            // surround each item with nowrap span
            currentCode[ c ] = '<span class="no-wrap-hyphen">' + currentCode[ c ] + '</span>';
            if ( currentCode[ c ].indexOf( '.' ) > -1 ) {
                // add a zero size space at the start for periods
                currentCode[ c ] = '<span class="wrap-period">' + currentCode[ c ] + '</span>';
            }
        }

        codes[ i ].innerHTML = currentCode.join('');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution using jquery,

```js
$('.mypara').each(function () {
     var str = $(this).html();  
      var htmlfoo = str.split('.').join('</br>');
     $(this).html(htmlfoo);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<code class="mypara">
This is-the HTML if its - characters exceed 50. characters it should go-to next line
</code>

<code class="mypara">
This is the HTM-if its. characters exceed 50 - characters it should. go-to next-line
</code>
```